# UFW is blocking mailserver traffic (dovecot, postfix, MariaDB, Rspamd)

Tags: dovecot, fail2ban, ufw, phpmyadmin, rspamd

As described in the title, I am running a dovecot/postfix/Rspamd Mailservercombo with a MariaDB behind it.

I noticed how, in the last days, I couldn't receive/send any mail from my e-mail clients anymore. Thunderbird noticed too: It is not possible to connect with the SMTP Server anymore.

The only things I changed around this time are:

- I added a phpmyadmin access with additional linux user query from the apache2 Server and
- (on recommendation of a "friend") installed fail2ban as an additional protection against bruteforce requests against the webservices. I left it on the default settings, only changed the bantime to 1 hr.

Since then I removed and purged fail2ban, sure it was the problem. It wasn't. (?)

After reading the following output from syslog I traced it back to UFW:

[syslog output (masked)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBsX4.png)

UFW itself has following configuration:

```
# cat /etc/ufw/user.rules
*filter
:ufw-user-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-deny - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-allow - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit-accept - [0:0]
### RULES ###

### tuple ### allow tcp 22 0.0.0.0/0 any 0.0.0.0/0 in
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

### tuple ### allow tcp 2222 0.0.0.0/0 any 0.0.0.0/0 in
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT

### tuple ### allow tcp 25 0.0.0.0/0 any 0.0.0.0/0 in
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT

### tuple ### allow tcp 465 0.0.0.0/0 any 0.0.0.0/0 in
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT

### tuple ### allow tcp 587 0.0.0.0/0 any 0.0.0.0/0 in
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT

### tuple ### allow tcp 143 0.0.0.0/0 any 0.0.0.0/0 in
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT

### tuple ### allow tcp 993 0.0.0.0/0 any 0.0.0.0/0 in
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT

### tuple ### allow tcp 4190 0.0.0.0/0 any 0.0.0.0/0 in
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 4190 -j ACCEPT

### tuple ### allow tcp 80 0.0.0.0/0 any 0.0.0.0/0 in
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

### tuple ### allow tcp 443 0.0.0.0/0 any 0.0.0.0/0 in
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

### END RULES ###

### LOGGING ###
-A ufw-after-logging-input -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] " -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10
-A ufw-after-logging-forward -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] " -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10
-I ufw-logging-deny -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j RETURN -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10
-A ufw-logging-deny -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] " -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10
-A ufw-logging-allow -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] " -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10
### END LOGGING ###

### RATE LIMITING ###
-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/minute -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT
### END RATE LIMITING ###
COMMIT
```

As you can see on the last few entries, it seems to maybe be triggered by ufw-after-logging-input, ufw-after-logging-forward or ufw-logging-deny. However, this is where my 'knowledge' ends right now. The only thing I additionaly noticed was that the following line was marked red in the user.rules, but that could just be nothing...

[User.rules in the CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gElAl.png)

I re-installed fail2ban to do this:

```
# fail2ban-client status
Status
|- Number of jail:      1
`- Jail list:   sshd

# fail2ban-client status sshd
Status for the jail: sshd
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 1
|  |- Total failed:     158
|  `- File list:        /var/log/auth.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 1
   |- Total banned:     1
   `- Banned IP list:   112.xxx.xxx.xxx

# fail2ban-client set sshd unbanip 112.xxx.xxx.xxx
112.xxx.xxx.xxx

# fail2ban-client status sshd
[...]
   `- Banned IP list:
```

`/var/log/auth.log` lists many of this kind of entries, all from the SAME IP:

```
Jun 25 19:56:51 mail sshd[26691]: Connection closed by 112.xxx.xxx.xxx port 60391 [preauth]
Jun 25 19:56:52 mail sshd[26693]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.xxx.xxx.xxx  user=root
Jun 25 19:56:54 mail sshd[26693]: Failed password for root from 112.xxx.xxx.xxx port 64328 ssh2
Jun 25 19:56:54 mail sshd[26693]: Connection closed by authenticating user root 112.xxx.xxx.xxx port 64328 [preauth]
Jun 25 19:57:03 mail sshd[26697]: Connection closed by 112.xxx.xxx.xxx port 50264 [preauth]
```

This can't be me as I am never logging in with root.

---

I searched through plenty of sites but couldn't find any useful lead on how to solve this. It really seems to have come from one of the recent changes I made, although I can't think of anything more than maybe a not deleted rule that may be still around after purging and removing fail2ban.

Some things I also tried in the process of fixing it:
- restarting and stop/starting UFW
- restarting apache2
- restarting dovecot
- looking on Rspamd for event entries on sent test-mails (none were received since the time around the changes I made!)
- using another mailclient
- adding an acceptance rule for Port 25 to UFW (did not change anything)

P.S.: This server is running Ubuntu.

Is there any way to get my setup back to a working state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now seem, after many tries, to have fixed my problem. Some hints to solve this:

No, it has nothing to do with those UFW-Blocks.
First off, **check if you are working with the correct service names!** I forgot that, because of a bug, I startet postfix with another servicename than you would normally.

You can propably see if you have the wrong servicename by comparing if this part of `systemctl status <servicename>.service` is identical on your server:

```
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-postfix.slice/<servicename>.service
           ├─5832 /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/master -w
           ├─5833 pickup -l -t unix -u -c
           └─5834 qmgr -l -t unix -u
```

My wrong service had only on CGroup under it's name.

After having the right servicename I could find the problem really quick as `systemctl status <servicename>.service` now put out proper error messages:

```
Jun 26 18:32:40 mail postmulti[6814]: /usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: mua_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
Jun 26 18:32:40 mail postmulti[6814]: /usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: mua_sender_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject_non_fqdn_sender,reject_sender_login_mismatch,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
Jun 26 18:32:40 mail postmulti[6814]: /usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: mua_relay_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

These are the result of a wrong main.cf and master.cf configuration. Both configs depend on each other, if you copy/paste you'll need both from one single source!

---

I also got the following errors, which hint on a missing (or in my case damaged) implementation of the postfix-mysql packet. Just `apt-get remove postfix-mysql`
 and `apt-get install postfix-mysql` afterwards.

```
Jun 26 18:20:41 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[6252]: error: unsupported dictionary type: mysql
Jun 26 18:20:41 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[6252]: message repeated 3 times: [ error: unsupported dictionary type: mysql]
Jun 26 18:20:41 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[6252]: fatal: in parameter smtpd_relay_restrictions or smtpd_recipient_restrictions, specify at least one working instance of: reject_unauth_destination, defer_unauth_destination, reject, defer, defer_if_permit or check_relay_domains
Jun 26 18:20:42 mail postfix/master[5832]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/smtpd pid 6252 exit status 1
Jun 26 18:20:42 mail postfix/master[5832]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
```

---

Another thing that could've done the trick is redoing the mysql user. I first added the user to the mysqldb by accessing the server with root on the commandline and entering `grant select on dbname.* to 'username'@'localhost' identified by 'verystrongpassword';`. I deleted that user now, replacing it with one I added with phpmyadmin and explicitly adding it to `'username'@'%'` instead of `'username'@'localhost'`.

---

One last thing I learned from this - if you add new packages to your server, check if there are dependencies that maybe interfere or would replace an already configured service. (`sendmail` could also be one of the problems that stopped my postfix server, sadly I can't confirm this after all of the other attempts)

Answer (score 0):

The UFW config looks correct.

You probably managed to ban your own IP in fail2ban.

Use `fail2ban-client status` to see which jails are enabled, then `fail2ban-client status <jail>` to see if your IP address is listed. If you find your IP, you can unban it.

```
[root@localhost ~]# fail2ban-client status 
Status
|- Number of jail:      1
`- Jail list:   sshd

[root@localhost ~]# fail2ban-client status sshd
Status for the jail: sshd
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 3
|  |- Total failed:     762
|  `- Journal matches:  _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sshd.service + _COMM=sshd
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 13
   |- Total banned:     86
   `- Banned IP list:   121.136.181.58 212.224.124.98 65.94.147.197 176.159.245.52 68.32.77.29 112.17.128.44 220.81.48.50 104.210.60.66 104.211.60.207 104.211.46.110 212.64.98.92 59.144.137.186 90.3.202.234

[root@localhost ~]# fail2ban-client set sshd unbanip 203.0.113.187
203.0.113.187
```

Comment: I installed fail2ban again to test it out and `apt remove fail2ban --purge` afterwards. 
I added the results to the initial question for better readability.

Sadly no change in the errors.